# Understanding this statement of logic by Bertrand Russell

Tags: logic

I'm trying to understanding this logic statement, and don't know where to begin. In *The History of Western Philosophy*, Bertrand Russell says "I have two hands" means "There is an a such that there is a b such that a and b are not identical and whatever x may be, 'x is a hand of mine' is true when, and only when, x is a or x is b."

I don't understand how to interpret the logical statement and why it is the same as "I have two hands." How would I break this down? Thanks!

Comment: Both sentences are in English. Presumably you're having trouble making sense of the second one. Can you say more about what's tripping you up?

Comment: If it helps, the second sentence corresponds closely to the symbolic version: $\exists a\exists b(a\ne b\land\forall x(h(x)\iff(x=a\lor x=b)))$, where $h(x)$ means "$x$ is a hand of mine".

Comment: Thanks. I update the question. I'm trying to understand how to break down the logic statement and don't understand why those two statements are equivalent.

Comment: @Karl Better might be to restrict $a$ and $b$ as follows: $\exists a \exists b( h(a) \land h(b) \land \forall x\cdots$

Answer (score 3):

Here's the translation with a few more intermediate steps:

"I have two hands" means:

> There exist two things (not just two names for the same thing) with the following property: Among *all* things, the things that fit the description "is a hand of mine" are precisely those two.

The first part

> There exist two things (not just two names for the same thing) with the following property: ...

can be stated as

> There exists an object (call it $a$) with the property that
>
> > there exists an object (call it $b$) with the property that
> >
> > > $a$ and $b$ are not the same object, and ...

Having introduced the names $a$ and $b$, we can restate the second part

> Among *all* things, the things that fit the description "is a hand of mine" are precisely those two.

as

> If the name $x$ refers to any object, then
>
> > the statement "$x$ is a hand of mine" is true if and only if $x$ refers to one of $a$ or $b$.

Rephrasing, we get Russel's sentence:

> There is an $a$ such that
>
> > there is a $b$ such that
> >
> > > $a$ and $b$ are not identical, and
> > >
> > > whatever $x$ may be,
> > >
> > > > '$x$ is a hand of mine' is true when, and only when, $x$ is $a$ or $x$ is $b$.

Comment: thank you. i would upvote, but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: +1.....Some allegedly accomplished philosophers, especially Wittgenstein, who was a student of Russell, persistently demonstrated a complete inability to understand this stuff.

Comment: One follow-up: the statement "there is an a such that there is a b ...". Is this just a list of objects, or is there a dependence between the two? The language seems to imply dependence or sequence.

Comment: I think you're noticing something about the order-dependence of quantifiers: consecutive existential quantifiers (the "there exists $x$ such that" phrases) can be reordered without changing the meaning of the sentence. So this sentence effectively just says "there is a pair of objects $(a,b)$ such that ...". The same is true of consecutive universal quantifiers ("for all $a$, for all $b$, ..."). But order is important when we mix the two kinds of quantifier: "for all $a$, there exists $b$ such that ..." is different from "there exists $b$ such that for all $a$, ...".